# How to put tooltip animation on chart areas?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to put some animation on my tooltip for my chart areas, I already write the code. It seems fine because there are no errors showing.

I already tried all I know but I think something is wrong with my code.

```
PM0chart.Series["y"].Points.AddXY(pm0timefin[i].ToString(),pm0kwhfin[i].ToString());

toolTip1 = new ToolTip();

toolTip1.ToolTipTitle = "Button Tooltip";

toolTip1.UseFading = true;

toolTip1.UseAnimation = true;

toolTip1.IsBalloon = true;

toolTip1.ShowAlways = true;  

toolTip1.AutoPopDelay = 5000;  

toolTip1.InitialDelay = 1000;  

toolTip1.ReshowDelay = 500;  

toolTip1.SetToolTip = pm0kwh[i] + " mV" + " on " pm0timefin[i];
```

I already have the result but I want to add animation on my tooltip.

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4km4y.png)

Comment: Can you add more information to your question? What kind of library are you using to create the charts?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page! - With the exception of the __syntax error on the last line__,  the code does bring up a tooltip with animation effects. - Also note MSDN: _interface effects such as window fading and animation. __If the user has not disabled__ these capabilities, the UseAnimation property can be used to enable this capability_

Comment: Sorry. This is for WinForms.

Comment: Looks like you don't code the tooltip target correctly as if is not shown as balloon. Start by replacing the last line by `toolTip1.SetToolTip(PM0chart, "testing");`

Comment: Doesn't work, it says that function is expected.